# Javascript receiving Resource object containing chars instead of String

Tags: javascript, java, string, char, angular-resource

My Java code should return user login as a String, but on Javascript side I'm receiving a strange Resource object whose numbered attributes each contains one char.

Here is my Java code:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/account/reset_password/finish", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<String> finishPasswordReset(@RequestBody KeyAndPasswordVM keyAndPassword) {
        if (!checkPasswordLength(keyAndPassword.getNewPassword())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Incorrect password", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return userService.completePasswordReset(keyAndPassword.getNewPassword(), keyAndPassword.getKey()).map(
                user -> new ResponseEntity<String>(user.getLogin(), HttpStatus.OK)).orElse(
                new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
    }
```

Javascript controller code:

```
Auth.resetPasswordFinish({key: $stateParams.key, newPassword: vm.resetAccount.password}).then(function (userLogin) {
                    vm.success = 'OK';
                    console.log("userLogin="+userLogin);
                }).catch(function () {
                    vm.success = null;
                    vm.error = 'ERROR';
                });
```

The console prints:

```
userLogin=[object Object]
```

which is not very interesting.

Inspecting the received object gives:
[image: Angular Resource object]

One can see that each char of the String is a numbered attribute of the Resource object.

Javascript Auth code:

```
function resetPasswordFinish (keyAndPassword, callback) {
    var cb = callback || angular.noop;

    return PasswordResetFinish.save(keyAndPassword, function (userLogin) {
        return cb(userLogin);
    }, function (err) {
        return cb(err);
    }).$promise;
}
```

This one is just passing the parameter to the callback function.

Do you know how to receive a plain String instead of this Resource object? I apologize if this is a trivial question.

I know that doing this will work in order to retrieve the user login:

```
var i = 0;
var userLoginToString = "";
while (typeof userLogin[String(i)] !== 'undefined') {
    userLoginToString += String(userLogin[String(i)]);
    i += 1;
}
```

however I don't think that this is the intended way to use this Resource object.

Comment: In your java code, what does `userService.completePasswordReset(keyAndPassword.getNewPassword(), keyAndPassword.getKey()).map(
                user -> new ResponseEntity<String>(user.getLogin(), HttpStatus.OK)).orElse(
                new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));` actually create after running?

Comment: @Joffutt This java codes creates a ResponseEntity whose body is user login and HTTP status is OK.
`<200 OK,test2,{}>`

Comment: Can you add the code for `Auth. resetPasswordFinish`?

Comment: @Joffutt I added it to the question, but this one is just passing the answer to the callback function.

Comment: You are getting a Javascript object back instead of a string because the return value of your java function is an object and not just a string. Unless you need to return a `ResponseEntity` for a specific reason, you should be able to return just a `String`

Comment: @Joffutt You're right, but I think I will keep returning a ResponseEntity since it holds the HttpStatus that will convey different error codes. For the moment I will keep using a while loop to aggregate chars to a String.